# I am having trouble with toggleClass jQuery method with Bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

This question is as frustrating as it is embarrassing for me to ask. I'm having trouble with Twitter Bootstrap and jquery. I suspect it's an issue with the selectors, because this same click event works if I attach a: console.log(this) and it works. Suspiciously in Firefox but not chrome but I will check this out in a different question or do separate testing/research.

I want to use the **.toggleClass()** on a carousel the **div(#myCarousel)**, and another **div(.accessibleView)** by clicking a **selector('#accessible')**.

**Here is the html:**

```
<input id="accessible" type="button" value="Switch to Accessibility mode"/>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="18000" data-pause="hover"   style="height:auto;">
 </div>
```

**Here is the CSS(which is in a scss file):**

```
    .hideCarousel{
          display: none !important;
     }
    .showAccess{
        display: block !important;
     }
    .accessibleView{
        display:none!important;
     }
```

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
$("#accessible").click(function(){
      $('.carousel').toggleClass("hideAccess");
        $('.accessibleView').toggleClass("showAccess");
 }
```

I suspect it's something wrong with the query selectors, but I can't be sure. This is a great community and I want to thank you in advance for any suggestions and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, I hope it will work for you::

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#accessible").click(function(){
      $('.carousel').toggleClass("hideAccess");
      $('.accessibleView').toggleClass("showAccess");
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it didn't work for me, friend.